# rspec - etc LoadError in Big Sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm having a trouble while running rspec in my project
Everything else runs normally, both server and console, while rspec isn’t
The problem is with etc gem, but I still can use Etc module in my rails console.

Ruby 2.7.1 built with rbenv
MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3

`` /Users/***/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require': cannot load such file -- etc (LoadError) ``
What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Is the etc gem loaded in the test environment?  Check Gemfile...

Comment: It's strange but rails console doesn't work with RAILS_ENV=test and gives the same error. @SteveTurczyn but that gem is default, so how can't it be loaded in the environment?

Comment: The gem is in your project Gemfile ?  Can you publish your Gemfile so we can see?